# SQL query having two IN operator with comparison being performed index wise

Tags: mysql, django

I have a use case in which I have two lists which are my search criteria and I need to write a query which will result in such a way that the searching is done by taking each element from each of the list one by one and performing the query operation.

Example:

```
list1 = (1,2,3,4,5);
list2 = (21,23,27,26,28);
select * from table where column1 in list1 and column2 in list2;
```

Query should work like:

```
select * from table where column1=1 and column2=21;
select * from table where column1=2 and column2=23;
select * from table where column1=3 and column2=27;
and so on.....
```

Note: I have to make this query in Django, so Django's model query will also work in case SQL query doesn't fit here.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: @Larnu, sure thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly. Assuming both lists have the same length, should it be simple like this?

## Edit: you can use Q objects to combine your filters

```
from django.db.models import Q

q_obj = Q()
for i in range(len(list1)):
    q_obj |= Q(column1=list1[i]) & Q(column2=list2[i])
    
result = Table.objects.filter(q_obj )
```

Comment: yes both the list will have same length but the point with above solution is that in case of large lists this will not be an optimised solution as we will be querying the database n number of times equal to the length of that list, which is not good performance wise.

Comment: @LovVerma I see that you want to union/concat all the results?
Then the query should be `(column1=1 and column2=21) or (column1=2 and column2=23) ` right?

Comment: that's right... but I want to perform it in one query, and the above approach is not feasible when size of the list is large.

Comment: I'm guessing this will result in a query like `where (column1=1 and column2=123) or (column1=2 and column2=234) ...` which I think will do a full table scan.  I would suggest picking one of the columns that is indexed and adding an additional `in` condition, resulting in something like `where column1 in (1,2) and (column1=1 and column2=123) or (column1=2 and column2=234) ...)`

Comment: Thanks @ĐàoMinhHạt... your answer is pretty much relevant in my context.

Comment: @LovVerma how about select it as the valid answer :P